# Slurm : Incomplete job state save file, start with '-i' to ignore this

Tags: save, state, slurm

I changed in my conf file the `SelectType=select/linear` to `SelectType= select/cons_res` in order to be able to run multiple jobs in same time on my partition.

But when i try to apply my changes, i get this error message : *fatal: Incomplete job state save file, start with '-i' to ignore this*.

If i change again the select type, everything works fine. So i think the problem really comes from there but what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Im running Centos7, and i usually use `slurmctld -i` and then restart slurmctld.sercvice with `systemctl restart slurmctld`.

here is slurmctld's docs:
https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurmctld.html